# PERMISSION_DENIED while using Google Natural Language API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I [set up](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/common/auth#set_up_a_service_account) the Service Account and downloaded the credentials json file.

```
GoogleNLSample-479e92642552.json
```

Code:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("GoogleNLSample-479e92642552.json");
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is).createScoped(CloudNaturalLanguageAPIScopes.all());
languageApi = new CloudNaturalLanguageAPI.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                jacksonFactory, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                })
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

AnalyzeEntitiesRequest request =
                    new AnalyzeEntitiesRequest()
                            .setDocument(new Document().setContent(text).setType("PLAIN_TEXT").setLanguage("en"))
                            .setEncodingType("UTF8");
final CloudNaturalLanguageAPI.Documents.AnalyzeEntities analyze = languageApi.documents().analyzeEntities(request);

//Exception here
AnalyzeEntitiesResponse response = analyze.execute();
```

Stacktrace:

```
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err: {
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:   "code" : 403,
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:     "message" : "The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.",
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:     "reason" : "forbidden"
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:   } ],
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:   "message" : "The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.",
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err:   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
09-23 21:43:27.897 32562-677/com.sample.android W/System.err: }
```

[image]

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "***********",
  "private_key_id": "***********",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n***********\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "***********",
  "client_id": "***********",
  "auth_uri": "***********",
  "token_uri": "***********",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "***********",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "***********"
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you have registered you APP in the Google Developer Console ? This erros is related to you API Key, so or you are not sending your key or your key is for another API

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro  I registered an API Key, but where to use that? Check the screen shot in question. Thanks.

Comment: I never used this API specifically, but i think you are getting your api from the Json (`GoogleCredential.fromStream(is)`). In others API's, i declare the key in the manifest as `meta-data` an the cliente pick automattically like that : `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();`

Comment: You are using a Json sample right ? probabbily inside this JSON exist an entry like `api_key: "YOUR_API_KEY" ` mostly samples come this way

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro yes I am using a JSON sample but the data inside is fine, because it was downloaded from the cloud service.

Comment: The Json is where you use the API Key ?

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro I added the json file data. It has all the values already filled.

Comment: You did the last line of the link you posted ? put the credential in environment variables ? `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>`

Comment: Are you sure your Google API Client is connected before attempting to execute the request?

Comment: What's your scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to test the Quickstart steps of Natural Language API [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/getting-started). More specifically you should first make sure that:

- billing is enabled
- natural language API is [enabled](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=language.googleapis.com&_ga=1.123642633.38043386.1470057190)

After you have done some testing with curl, you can start experimenting in [Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/language/analysis).

However, note that there is a difference between API keys and the service account credentials. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/common/auth#set_up_a_service_account) for an in depth explanation for the differences. Basically, the API key is not in the JSON file and it just provides another/easier way to interact with the API.

**Edit:**
As noted by @archie-bpgc there was also a line  missing in the initialize: callback `credential.initialize(request);`

Comment: Where you able to perform the tests?

Comment: Actually I was missing a line in the initialize callback `credential.initialize(request);` That solved the issue. Pleas add that as your answer. Thanks.